# Heatmap rendering issue at certain zoom with certain radius

Tags: google-maps-api-3, heatmap

Using GoogleMaps API v3.19, 3.20 or 3.exp, when I set a radius to a heatmap layer, at certain zoom level the render disappears and Chrome's console gives an error as 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '84' of undefined`, where `'84'` is sometimes different depending on the coordinate. Also, zooming in far from the area which the heatmap is applied, no error is shown, though navigating to the area even at greater zoom, I got the very same error and the layer just stuck like JPEG artifacts, which let me believe that there is something wrong with coordinates.

Zooming in and out does not solve the issue.

Any advise on this subject? Any known bug?

UPDATE (sharing some code of radius value change):

```
    // heatmarkers is an array of WeightedLocation
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data     : heatmarkers,
        radius   : 27
    });

    heatmap.setMap(myMap);

    google.maps.event.addListener(myMap, 'zoom_changed', function(){
        if (heatmap){
            var zoom = myMap.getZoom();

            if (zoom >= 14){
                heatmap.set('radius', 90);
            } else {
                heatmap.set('radius', zoom * 2);    
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share some minimal code to actually see what you try?

Comment: I added but, I can't believe that this is syntax related since everything continues to work as it should even the layer itself is render. It just stop working after some level of zoom.

Comment: You can check the example [here](http://output.jsbin.com/rorecuce/1/), it might be help.

Comment: @bjiang That doesn't help at all. As I said, it can be rendered, at certain zoom rate and radius those errors start to show up. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had exactly the same problem and solved it by reducing the number of decimals in the coordinates of my heatmap data, e.g.:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      6.76483154296875,
      51.226775403420554
    ]
  }
}
```

was changed to:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      6.7648315429,
      51.22677540342
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well that fixed the navigation with defined zoom. The thing is, adding a range input that control the heatmap radius of each point cause the error once again. Since that is not the meaning of the main question, I'll check your answer. But still, if anyone have any idea about changing radius on the fly, please let me know.